# Функция шифрования и дешифрования для массивв

Tags: c#, .net

Появилась необходимость зашифровать массив байт и потом расшифровать его и на выходе тоже получить массив. Всё что не находил было либо для строк, либо для чего-то другого. Случайно нет ни у кого готовой функции?

Comment: Сериализуйте массив каким-нибудь форматом в строку и потом шифруйте

Comment: Существует более одного алгоритма шифрования. Примените операцию `xor 5` к каждому байту, например.

Comment: Вообще-то наоборот, все встроенные в шарп алгоритмы шифрования работают с массивами, а не со строками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например так

```
static class Protector
{
    // соль должна быть не меньше 8 байт
    private static readonly byte[] salt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("3DOTOTOS");
    // итераций должно быть не меньше 1000
    private static readonly int iterations = 2000;

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение экземпляра AES
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">применяемый пароль</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр AES</returns>
    private static Aes GetAesInstance(string password)
    {
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);

        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
        aes.IV = pbkdf2.GetBytes(16);
        return aes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Зашифровка байтового массива
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainBytes">входной незашифрованный байтовый массив</param>
    /// <param name="password">пароль</param>
    /// <returns>зашифрованный байтовый массив</returns>
    public static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] plainBytes, string password)
    {
        if (plainBytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainBytes));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        Aes aes = GetAesInstance(password);

        byte[] result;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            }
            result = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Дешифровка байтого массива
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="secretBytes">массив байтов секретной части изображения</param>
    /// <param name="password">пароль</param>
    /// <returns>дешифрованный массив байт</returns>
    public static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] secretBytes, string password)
    {
        if (secretBytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secretBytes));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        Aes aes = GetAesInstance(password);

        byte[] result;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(secretBytes, 0, secretBytes.Length);
            }
            result = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string password = "12Обезьян";
        byte[] array = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Массив байт.");

        byte[] cryptArray = Protector.EncryptBytes(array, password);
        byte[] decryptArray = Protector.DecryptBytes(cryptArray, password);

        var result = array.SequenceEqual(decryptArray);

        Console.WriteLine($"Массивы равны? {result}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```